# ESB 4.8.1 with Data Service Hosting feature cannot use boxcarring

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I run the following code in a WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 server with Data service Hosting feature 4.2.4 installed. I did some research on web, the normal response of "begin_boxcar" request should return a session cookie, however it doesn't. I also tried to send the same request to a standalone DSS 3.2.2 server. I did return a session cookie. Anyone can help?

```
<header name="Action" value="urn:begin_boxcar"></header>
 <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
       <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:dat="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
          <soapenv:Header></soapenv:Header>
          <soapenv:Body>
             <dat:begin_boxcar></dat:begin_boxcar>
          </soapenv:Body>
       </soapenv:Envelope>
    </format>
 </payloadFactory>
 <call>
    <endpoint key="GS1OrderDS"></endpoint>
 </call>
 <log level="full">
    <property name="==============Set-Cookie===============" expression="get-property('transport','Set-Cookie')"></property>
 </log>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Cookie value from

```
<property name="setCookieHeader" expression="$trp:Set-Cookie"/>
```

For the subsequent calls the Cookie can be set by

```
<property name="Cookie" expression="get-property('setCookieHeader')"
               scope="transport"/>
```

Hope this helps!